# How can i use Google Assistant SDK + Dialogflow by CLI(Command Line Interface)?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I want to make a small AI speaker.

It looks like Google Home, Apple Homepod.

I installed the Google Assist SDK on my Ubuntu 16.04.
I can register an action through gactions.

$ pushtotalk.py --device-model-id ~
I can use the Google assistant like this.

But the dialogue flow is only on the simulator in the actions on google web page.
Can I use it like pushtotalk.py and can I use intents in the dialogue flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Assistant SDK is just like using the Google Assistant. If you want, you can invoke and communicate with Dialogflow apps just like on a phone.

`pushtotalk.py ... "Talk to my app"`

`pushtotalk.py ... "Hello"`

That will go on as you want. You can also access 3P actions like Number Genie.

Comment: I think part of the issue here is that their action isn't published yet, so they need to authenticate their Assistant SDK device.

Comment: Thank you vvvvery much ... That's exactly what I was looking for.